# Ollydbg instructions before program

Tags: reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I am new to reverse engineering, and I have been looking at a simple program:

```
char* a = "hello world";
printf(a);
```

However, when I open this in ollydbg, I am not taken right to the assembly as I would have been in gdb, there are many more instructions first.  I was wondering why this was happening.

Thanks!

Comment: So are you saying that you are taken to _some_ assembly code, just not what you were expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how you attach to the program with olly, you'll be take to one of two places(if no errors occurred):

- The module entry point (aka the system glue and CRT wrapper for `main`/`WinMain`/`DllMain`): this occurs when you start a program with olly.
- `NtUserBreakPoint`: this is when you attach to an existing process.

To navigate to where you want you can use `ctrl + e` to bring up the modules window, from there, select the module you want. Then use `crtl + n` to bring up the symbols window for your current module (note: for non-exported symbols to be available, the pdb's need to be available or you need to perform an object scan of your obj's for that build).

if your taken to the `ModuleEntryPoint` you can also just spelunk down the call chain (generally you want the second call/jmp), this gets you to the crt entrypoint, from there just look for a call with 3/5/4 args, this will be `main`/`WinMain`/`DllMain`:

from here:

```
Blackene.<ModuleEntryPoint> 004029C3                                   E8 FC030000                                             CALL Blackene.__security_init_cookie
004029C8                                                             ^ E9 D7FCFFFF                                             JMP Blackene.__tmainCRTStartup
```

we goto here:

```
Blackene.__tmainCRTStartup 004026A4                                    6A 58                                                   PUSH 58
004026A6                                                               68 48474000                                             PUSH Blackene.00404748
004026AB                                                               E8 1C060000                                             CALL Blackene.__SEH_prolog4
004026B0                                                               33DB                                                    XOR EBX,EBX
```

then scroll down here:

```
004027D3                                                               6A 0A                                                   PUSH 0A
004027D5                                                               58                                                      POP EAX
004027D6                                                               50                                                      PUSH EAX
004027D7                                                               56                                                      PUSH ESI
004027D8                                                               6A 00                                                   PUSH 0
004027DA                                                               68 00004000                                             PUSH Blackene.00400000
004027DF                                                               E8 2CF2FFFF                                             CALL Blackene.WinMain
```

*I'm assuming ollydbg 1.10 is being used.*